# Problems with "simple" table

Tags: tables

After lots of attempts, I've been unable to get a table ***exactly*** as the one below. I don't know if somebody could give me some advice. [image].

I took the code of another table and managed to get this:

```
\begin{longtable}[c]{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{3-6}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{X} \\
\cline{3-6}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}& & 1& 2& 3\\
\hline \multirow{2}{*}{$Y$}
& 1& 0.23 & 1 & 232.23 \\
\cline{2-6}
& 2& 0  & -21 & 0\\
\cline{2-6}
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

But the result is far from what I want. Besides, when I try to compile the whole document, not just the table, I got some errors related to the `longtable` package.

Many thanks!
C.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I can understand you need this table. It's difficult to reproduce in LaTeX because it's a very badly shaped table, I hope you agree. `;-)`

Comment: I agree it is difficult. Otherwise, I could have done it.

Comment: What have you managed to do so far? Please share a base code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation with low level commands

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\thickhrulefill}{%
 \leavevmode\leaders\hrule height.4pt depth.6pt\hfill\kern 0pt
}


\begin{document}

\begingroup\sffamily\offinterlineskip
\tabskip=0pt
\halign{%
  #&
  \vrule#\hfil &
  \kern0.8pt \vrule#&
  \makebox[.25in]{#}&
  \vrule#\hfil &
  \makebox[1in]{\strut#}&
  \hfil\vrule#\hfil &
  \makebox[1in]{\strut#}&
  \hfil\vrule#\hfil &
  \makebox[1in]{\strut#}&
  \hfil\vrule#\hfil
\cr
\multispan{4}&\multispan{7}\hfil\strut X\hfil\cr
\multispan{4}&\multispan{7}\hrulefill\cr
\multispan{4}& height .8pt &\multispan{5}&\cr
\multispan{4}&\multispan{7}\hrulefill\cr
\multispan{4}&&1&&2&&3&\cr
\omit & height.4pt depth .6pt &\omit\hrulefill\vrule depth.6pt &\hrulefill &\multispan{7}\thickhrulefill\cr
\smash{\lower.6\normalbaselineskip\hbox{Y }}&&&1& width 1pt &0.23&&1&&232.23&\cr
\omit&&&\multispan{8}\hrulefill\cr
&&&2& width 1pt &0&&--21&&0&\cr
\omit&\multispan{10}\hrulefill\cr
}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

And now a perhaps preferable rendering

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\begin{document}

\begingroup\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{
  >{\centering}p{.25in}
  >{\centering}p{1in}
  >{\centering}p{1in}
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1in}
}
\toprule
Y & \multicolumn{3}{c}{X} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-4}
& 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-4}
1 & 0.23 & 1 & 232.23 \\
2 & 0 & --21 & 0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, egreg! This is exactly what I wanted to get. Many thanks for your help! C.